# New value on the record's field is reverted to the old value when updating via Salesforce SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, test-automation

I'm updating some test Contacts' emails in a test automation script.
I'm using [generated Enterprise API Java "stubs"](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc), so the `enterpriseConnection` object is for SOAP API interactions with my test sandbox.

Here's a piece of code that we use for it. Notice that `update()` takes all the records at once:

```
var testEmail = UUID.randomUUID() + "@example.com";
contactOne.setEmail(testEmail);
contactTwo.setEmail(testEmail);
contactThree.setEmail(testEmail);

var contactsToUpdate = new SObject[]{contactOne, contactTwo, contactThree};
var saveResults = enterpriseConnection.update(contactsToUpdate);
```

The issue is that *sometimes* one of the contacts' emails is updated to a new value and then *reverts back to the previous one*. I checked Apex triggers and Automation processes that we have, and it doesn't seem to be their doing.

[image: Contact History on one of the Contacts with this issue]

I don't remember having this when updating one record at a time, but I've seen quite a few cases where this happened when we sent multiple records in one SOAP `update()` request.

Has anyone ever faced this? What could be the reason behind such behavior? Maybe it's my org's configuration after all?

Comment: Have you tried to set debug logs for the user and check variable_assignment statement there? May be helpful in your case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova so far, every time we did so, there have been no such incidents. But I guess this is the only thing that's left on our side to get some more understanding.